# WP7 Umlauts and Special Characters

Tags: windows-phone-7, diacritics

I'm facing an encoding problem in WP7. I make a json request to an API, the response includes German umlauts but for some reason it shows up incorrectly.
That's the code for making the request:

```
public static void makeRequest(string requestString,List<String> parameters,Action<string> handleRequestResult)
    {
        //generate a random nonce and a timestamp
        Random rand = new Random();
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        string nonce1 = rand.Next().ToString();
        string nonce2 = rand2.Next().ToString();
        string nonce = nonce1 + nonce2;
        string timestamp = GetTimestamp();

        //create the parameter string in alphabetical order
        //string parameters = "oauth_callback=" + UrlHelper.Encode("http://www.example.com");
        parameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key=" + ConsumerKey);
        parameters.Add("oauth_nonce=" + nonce);
        parameters.Add("oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1");
        parameters.Add("oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp);
        parameters.Add("oauth_version=1.0");

        //sorting the list of parameters (adding '&' between them)
        string sortedParameters = sortParams(parameters);

        //generate a signature base on the current requeststring and parameters and adding it to request string
        string signature = generateSignature("GET", requestString, sortedParameters);
        string url = requestString + "?" + sortedParameters + "&oauth_signature=" + signature;

        //test the request
        WebClient web2 = new WebClient();
        web2.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        //string result = web.DownloadString(url);
        web2.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            string result = (string)e.Result;
            handleRequestResult(result);
            

            //App.ViewModel.LoadData(result);
        };
        web2.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
```

And here's an example code for loading the response to the view:

```
public void LoadBlogPosts(string content)
    {
        
        if (!AddToExistingBlogs)
        {
            this.BlogPosts.Clear();
        }
        

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(content);
        foreach (XElement element in xml.Descendants("item"))
        {
            BlogViewModel newBlog = new BlogViewModel();
            newBlog.Title = element.Element("title").Value;
            newBlog.Description = element.Element("description").Value;
            newBlog.Link = element.Element("link").Value;
            newBlog.Category = element.Element("category").Value;
            //newBlog.Comments = element.Element("comments").Value;
            newBlog.PubDate = element.Element("pubDate").Value;
            XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
            XNamespace wfw = "http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/";
            XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
            XNamespace sy = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/";
            XNamespace slash = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/";
            XNamespace contentn = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";
            newBlog.Dccreator = element.Element(dc + "creator").Value;
            newBlog.Guid = element.Element("guid").Value;
            newBlog.WfwCommentRss = element.Element(wfw + "commentRss").Value;
            newBlog.SlashComments = element.Element(slash + "comments").Value;
            newBlog.Content = "<html><body style='color: white; background-color:Black'>";
            newBlog.Content += element.Element(contentn + "encoded").Value;
            newBlog.Content += "</body></html>";

            //
            //Extract images from post:
            //
            // Size the control to fill the form with a margin

            var reg = new Regex("src=(?:\"|\')?(?<imgSrc>[^>]*[^/].(?:jpg|bmp|gif|png))(?:\"|\')?");
            var match = reg.Match(newBlog.Content);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                newBlog.FeaturedImage = match.Groups["imgSrc"].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                newBlog.FeaturedImage = @"http://karkur.com/no_image.png";
            }
            


            BlogPosts.Add(newBlog);

        }

    }
```

That's the result that I get:
[image]

Basically what I need is something to unescape unicode characters in WP7:
convert this: [image]

to normal characters

Answer (score 0):

You should set you encoding to ISO-8859-1. So, in you case:

```
web2.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't change anything!

Comment: Shouldn't matter, it displays german when I get respone with XML so that's no the problem.

Comment: Can you paste the top part your xml data that you get? Basically from the doc root until you say it is correctly formatted. Thanks.